# Trying to get the Xamarin xam.plugin.hud library to work on Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to get the Xamarin xam.plugin.hud library to work on the Android phone.  It works with iOS but I cannot seem to get it to work on Android.

I get this exception whenever I try to access any method from that library.  The exception is:
Unhandled Exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: void AndroidHUD.AndHUD.ShowToast(Android.Content.Context,string,AndroidHUD.MaskType,System.Nullable`1,bool,System.Action,System.Action) occurred

I have tried using different versions of AndHUD and of XAM.Plugin.HUD.  My target framework is Android 8.1.  I can use AndHud and use the ShowToast method directly in my android project.

Comment: I'm confused about which library are you using? AndHUD and XAM.Plugin.HUD are two different libraries.

Comment: The XAM.Pluing.HUD Nuget package requires the AndHud Nuget package to work on Android.  It also requires the BTProgressHUD to show huds on iOS.

Comment: Are you building a xamarin.Android project? Or a xamarin.forms project?